# Executing js based on security

Tags: javascript, .net, webforms

I have an internal .NET 4.0 web forms app with a sql server backend. I have a menu on the home screen that I need to show/hide parts of based on which groups the user is in. I am struggling with the best way to do this. In the past I have called js functions from the code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. However, I feel like this is bad practice and don't want to keep doing it if it is. I know I could just set my html table cells that need manipulating to runat server and add the property in the code behind when I lookup the user's security. Should I do that and forget about trying to go back and forth between the code behind and js? Or, is there a way to accomplish this that is good web programming practice?

Seems like this is a common scenario, which is why I think I'm missing something obvious. Lookup something from database, then execute js to manipulate front end.

Note: I bounce between plain js and jQuery, so feel free to answer with either.

Comment: This is considerably simpler to do in MVC (I know that's likely not helpful but it's an FYI, In my opinion anyone still using Webforms should be looking into moving to MVC)

Comment: Ya, maybe that is part of my confusion. I'm thinking it should be easy to do, because it IS easy to do......in MVC. Unfortunately, I don't think the team is going to be interested in moving this app to MVC. It's not worth it for this change. However, I am pushing future apps to be in MVC. Any idea what the best practice is in Web Forms?

Comment: It's kinda tricky because of the whole post-back malarky. I'd forget the js and just get the code behind to do it for you. Ultimately if it's the users groups then this is pretty static(?) so shouldn't change. So just render whatever the user should see on load and be done with it.

Comment: Exactly right. It's not going to change during a session or anything. It just seemed like I should be able to do all of my UI manipulations client-side, but I guess I'm still thinking MVC. I don't really have any issue doing it server side on load. I just was looking for confirmation that I wasn't missing a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you want you client to be pure js then web forms is not for you! You pretty much need to do some processing server side because it won't deal with a plain js call